# FULLTEXT searching wont suffice, need workaround, any ideas?

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I can currently not use FULLTEXT indexes to search whole words because my server wont allow less characters than 4 in a search string.

I need a workaround then from you guys.

I want to be able to enter 'bmw 330' and then get results from mysql with whole matches like 'bmw 330'.

Should I consider a third party search engine for this?

How can I do this in PHP ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match exactly, then you want

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE text_column = 'bmw 330'
```

.

Comment: Does this come out true, even if the text_column is 'bmw 330 in mint condition' ?

Comment: OK, it doesn't. You'll probably need a little more filtering code or go with Jan's suggestion and use Lucene or something.

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like [Zend Lucene](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.html). It's written in PHP so you don't need to install anything.

Comment: Lucene or Sphinx are both great search solutions that integrate easily with PHP

Comment: indeed! However the problem is that he probably can't install Sphinx, that is why I didn't recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

So what if you write SQL like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE text_column LIKE '%bmw 330%'
```

?

Comment: I have tried that, it wont work, should it? Because when I tried it returned 'bmw 330' even if I wrote 'bm'...

Comment: Oh... then you don't want LIKE, you want... my next answer.

Answer (score 1):

You say "my server" so I suppose you have direct access to its configuration:

You can change the min characters required for an FULLTEXT search in MySQL, just change the following line (in my.cnf) to fit your needs:

```
[mysqld]
ft_min_word_len=3
```

Best wishes,
Fabian

Comment: no I dont have direct access... i meant my webhosting company... sorry

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%bmw 330%' ?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE text_column LIKE '% bmw 330 %'
```

(note the spaces after and before the %)

?

Some limitations: It will find full words, but won't find

```
bmw 330(mint condition)
SPECIAL OFFER!!!!!bmw 330
```

Answer (score 0):

All right, you have a number of suggestions here now. The best way is most certainly using a specialized search engine like Lucene.

If you can't use something like Lucene, I have an idea for a **massively hacky** workaround.

- Create a second text field in your table
- Whenever your text field is updated, write a copy of it into the second text field. Use a regex to find words less than 4 characters long and add a pre-defined string to every occurrence:
  `bmw` => `bmwABCDEF`
- For every incoming search query, use the same regex to add the string to every word < 4 characters. `bmw 300` will then become `bmwABCDEF 300ABCDEF` and matched accordingly.

It's very hacky and needs to be throught through for possible side effects, but might work better than nothing.

Comment: interesting approach ... but very hacky indeed